# QueryWorkingSet always returning false

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get the size of allocated are for a process, descriminated by image, private and mapped. I'm using QueryWorkingSet to get the Working Set Information and then the Working Set Block.

When i called it for the first time, the GetLastError method return 24 which is to be expected so the next time I call QueryWorkingSet I set a diferent size for the block but then im getting an error code of 998.

Am I using QueryWorkingSet wrong or Im getting the handle for the process with the wrong access rights or Im the resize is not enough?

```
#include "pch.h"
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include<WinDef.h>
 #include <psapi.h>
 #include <iostream>

typedef struct {
    DWORD img;
    DWORD map;
    DWORD prv;
} CommitCounters, *PCommitCounters;


BOOL  GetCommitCountersFromProcess(_In_ int pid, _Out_ PCommitCounters committedCounter ) {
    int numberOfTries = 3;
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    DWORD pageSz = si.dwPageSize;

    PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION wsi, *pwsi;
    pwsi = &wsi;
    DWORD ws_size;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi, *pmbi;
    pmbi = &mbi;

    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    wsi.NumberOfEntries = 0;

    QueryWorkingSet(processHandle, &wsi, sizeof(pwsi));
    BOOL res = false;
    committedCounter->img = 0;
    committedCounter->map = 0;
    committedCounter->prv = 0;

    while (numberOfTries > 0) {
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();

        //ERROR_BAD_LENGTH
    if (lastError == 24) {
        ws_size = sizeof(wsi) + sizeof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION) + sizeof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK) * wsi.NumberOfEntries;
        pwsi = (PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION*) malloc(ws_size);

        pwsi->NumberOfEntries = wsi.NumberOfEntries;
        BOOL resQws = QueryWorkingSet(processHandle, &wsi, ws_size);
        DWORD teste = sizeof(wsi);
        if (resQws) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pwsi->NumberOfEntries; i++) {
                PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK ws_block = pwsi->WorkingSetInfo[1];
                //Access page information.
                SIZE_T size = VirtualQuery((LPCVOID*)ws_block.VirtualPage, &mbi, 1);
                if (size != 0 && pmbi ->State == 0x1000) {
                    switch (pmbi->Type)
                    {
                    case 0x1000000: // MEM_IMAGE
                        committedCounter->img += pageSz;
                        break;
                    case  0x40000: //MEM_MAPPED
                        committedCounter->map += pageSz;
                        break;
                    case 0x20000: //MEM_PRIVATE
                        committedCounter->prv += pageSz;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (size == 0) {
                    return res;
                }
            }
            CloseHandle(processHandle);
            res = true;
            return res;
        }
        free(pwsi); 
    }
        numberOfTries--;
}

    CloseHandle(processHandle);
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You don't have any real error checking here. How about you fix that next.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but im calling GetLastError() where im getting the value that I mention in the question

Comment: There are multiple calls to api functions without error checking. Perhaps one of them is failing. Because you don't check you can't know.

Comment: 3-rd parameter in call `QueryWorkingSet` - `sizeof(pwsi)` of course wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.  Just change:

```
BOOL resQws = QueryWorkingSet(processHandle, &wsi, ws_size);
```

to:

```
BOOL resQws = QueryWorkingSet(processHandle, pwsi, ws_size);
```

And then the call succeeds.

There may be further errors but I did not investigate those.

Comment: @David And then there is this line: `pwsi = (PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION*) malloc(ws_size)`.  I'm surprised you are 'gutted' when I have found and corrected the OP's problem, although, as I say, there are probably others.  For example, `PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK ws_block = pwsi->WorkingSetInfo[1];` looks wrong.

Comment: Hmm, OK, the second call to QueryWorkingSet